# nHibernate GeneratedBy.Assigned isn't working

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, insert

I am attempting to insert a record with a composite key (not my database design, and I'm forced to use corporates schema, so changing the DB is not an option here).

I have the following POCO class

```
public class RulesEngineHeader
{
    public virtual string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string RuleID { get; set; }
    public virtual string RuleGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual string RuleDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

and the following mapping (using Fluent)

```
internal class RulesEngineHeaderMap : ClassMap<RulesEngineHeader>
{
    internal RulesEngineHeaderMap()
    {
        Table("LIOEP023");

        Id(x => x.CompanyCode, "CONO23")
            .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
            .Length(2)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Id(x => x.RuleID, "RLID23")
            .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
            .Length(30)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.RuleGroup, "RGRP23")
            .Length(30)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.RuleDescription, "RLDS23")
            .Length(50)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Expression, "EXPR23")
            .Length(2500)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

using the following code:

```
using (iSeriesUOW uow = new iSeriesUOW())
{
    GenericRepository<RulesEngineHeader> rep = new GenericRepository<RulesEngineHeader>(uow);

    RulesEngineHeader header = new RulesEngineHeader();
    header.CompanyCode = "LI";
    header.RuleID = "TEST";
    header.RuleGroup = "AC";
    header.RuleDescription = "Description";
    header.Expression = "This is my rule expression";

    rep.Add(header);

    uow.Commit();
}
```

The rep.Add simply does a

```
_uow.Session.Save(entityObject);
```

and the uow.Commit(); does a 
    _session.Flush();

```
if (_tx != null)
    _tx.Commit();
```

When I execute this, I get the following query trying to be executed:

```
INSERT INTO LIOEP023
    (RGRP23,
    RLDS23,
    EXPR23,
    RLID23)
VALUES      ('AC' /* @p0_0 */,
    'Description' /* @p1_0 */,
    'This is my rule expression' /* @p2_0 */,
    'TEST' /* @p3_0 */)
```

As you can see, my CompanyCode/CONO23 is nowhere to be found, which is causing an error.

Any ideas why this is not being used in my insert??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that instead of using 2 Id's, I should use CompositeId.

So my code should look like this:

```
internal RulesEngineHeaderMap()
{
    Table("LIOEP023");

    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.CompanyCode, "CONO23")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.RuleID, "RLID23");
    Map(x => x.RuleGroup, "RGRP23")
        .Length(30)
        .Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.RuleDescription, "RLDS23")
        .Length(50)
        .Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Expression, "EXPR23")
        .Length(2500)
        .Not.Nullable();
}
```